# How to add arguments to onclick in javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick, arguments

Basically, when a button is pressed I want an argument to be supplied with it but this does not work:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onClick = doThis(arg);
```

but this does work (without arguments):

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onClick = doThis;
```

The reason why the first example doesn't work it because the function automatically runs without waiting for the click.

How do I supply arguments onClick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note that it's `onclick`, not `onClick`. Both work on major browsers, but the former is the correct capitalization. (See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-idl-attributes) in the HTML specification, including the code example.)

You have a couple of choices:

1. Use `Function#bind`:

   ```
   button.onclick = doThis.bind(button, arg);
   ```

   `Function#bind` creates a new function that, when called, will call the original with a specific `this` value (the first argument, `button` in our case) and any arguments you give it (followed by any arguments the new function is called with).
2. Use a wraper function:

   ```
   button.onclick = function() { doThis(arg); };
   ```

   within the above, though, `this` in `doThis` will not be the button. If you want it to be, you can use `Function#call`:

   ```
   button.onclick = function() { doThis.call(button, arg); };
   // or
   button.onclick = function() { doThis.call(this, arg); };
   ```

   `Function#call` calls a function, specifying the `this` value to use, along with the arguments to pass to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this using an anonymous function.

```
document.getElementById("button").onClick = function() { doThis(arg); };
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for even though it seems a bit strange. Thanks!

Comment: No idea on that. But @OP, I'd definitely go for accepting T.J's answer as it is much more complete than my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it well using `addEventListener` in `JavaScript`.
`HTML5` `data`-attributes and `DOMStringMap` can be utilized to extend it further.

Below code snippet should give you fair idea of using arguments with any `HTMLDomEvents`.

```
el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  performAction(e, this);
});
```

```js
var elContainer = document.querySelector('#myDiv');
var el = document.querySelector('#searchNow');

el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  performAction(e, this);
});

function performAction(e, thatObj) {
  var str = '' + e.type + '\n';
  for (x in thatObj.dataset) {
    str += x + ': ' + thatObj.dataset[x] + '\n';
  }

  console.log(e.type + thatObj.dataset);
  elContainer.innerHTML += str;

}
```

```css
#myDiv {
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  My DIV...
  <br/>
</div>

<button name='search' id='searchNow' data-propertiesObject='{a: "XYZ", b: "ABC"}'>Search Now!</button>
```